# bitaddress.org paper wallet vs. single wallet

Tags: wallet, paper-wallet, bitaddress.org

After generating a single wallet (at bitaddress.org), the paper wallet option at the top shows a different public address?  Why is the public address different?

Answer (score 3):

bitaddress.org does not use the same private keys for paper wallet generation as for the single wallet. It uses the same initial entropy that you provide, but new private keys are generated for the paper wallet. Thus the addresses are different.